# bash/sed/regex: insert a newline after a . symbol whenever a <char> follows a . symbol on the same line

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, sed

(This is my first question on stackoverflow so I apologize ahead of time if this question is poorly written. Critique is appreciated.)

**Overview of problem: **
I have a very long list of words in this format (example):

```
cow n.
sheep n.horse n.
fly n. , v.chicken n.
```

I need it to look like this:

```
cow n.
sheep n.
horse n.
fly n. , v.
chicken n.
```

**Details of the problem:**
In this list, we have three patterns that I am concerned with:

```
1. <char>.<newline># newline after the . symbol
2. <char>.<whitespace>,<whitespace><char>.<newline># whitespace after the . symbol, example: fly n. , v.
3. <char>.<char># char after the . symbol on the same line
```

I need to insert a newline wherever a `<char>` follows a . symbol on the same line. In this case,  will always be a lowercase English letter a to z.

will only exist after the . symbol when followed by a , symbol, like in pattern 4 above (example: fly n. , v.). In all other cases, a newline should follow every . symbol.

Other questions talk about inserting before or after a pattern, or in between two patterns, but this problem deals specifically with inserting within a single pattern.

**What I have attempted so far:**
I tested the regex with grep, yielding these results:

```
grep "[a-z].[a-z]" test.txt

cow n.
sheep n.horse n.
fly n. , v.chicken n.
```

The second [a-z] in the regex is apparently grabbing the first char of the new line.

I want it to grab only the things that look like this (example):

```
n.h
```

Not:

```
n.
h
```

Then, I need to insert a `<newline>` after the . symbol in bash/sed.

Comment: is it possible for whitespace (spaces, tabs) to exist between the `.` and `<char>`?  will `<char>` always be lowercase or could it include uppercase?  could `<char>` include characters that are not part of the alphabet (eg, numbers, punctuation marks)? could `<char>` include 'letters' from non-English languages (eg, characters that are supported by utf8)? please update the question with these additional details

Comment: based solely on the provided sample input: `\.[a-z]` should match the breakpoint; whether that's enough to process the input will depend on the tool you use

Comment: Why not `(\.)([a-z])` replace `$1\n$2` https://regex101.com/r/bjlS2K/1 Get someone to convert this to bash.

Comment: hello, thank you. I have updated the question with your requested details. I will also answer here for convenience - <char> will always be a lowercase English letter a to z. <whitespace> can only exist if the word has two chars following the word itself, e.g. fly<whitespace><char 1>.<whitespace>,<whitespace><char 2>.<newline> ; does this answer your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Using any `sed` that expands `\n` to a newline in the replacement text:

```
$ sed 's/\.\([a-z]\)/.\n\1/g' file
cow n.
sheep n.
horse n.
fly n. , v.
chicken n.
```

With any other sed it'd be either of these:

```
sed 's/\.\([a-z]\)/.\
\1/g' file

sed $'s/\.\([a-z]\)/.\\n\1/g' file

sed 's/\.\([a-z]\)/.\'$'\n''\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem:

`perl -i -pe 's/(\.)([a-z])/$1\n$2/g;' test.txt`